# Modify Interaction : How to just move vertices (of a LineString or Polygon) and not adding new vertices

Tags: openlayers

**OBJECTIVE:** I need to edit a vector layer by moving the existing vertices and not adding new ones because i have a table where i show the coords for each one. When i move a vertex i have to update the table.

**Investigation**:
I checked the documentation of openlayers 4.6.5 [Interaction Modify docs](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html)
and checked the "condition" option.

It says :

> A function that takes an ol.MapBrowserEvent and returns a boolean to indicate whether that event will be considered to add or move a vertex to the sketch. Default is ol.events.condition.primaryAction.

So that "add or move" is not what i want.

Is there a possibility to just move the vertices and not adding new ones?

Comment: What geometry you are trying to move is it Point or LineString or other?

Comment: @SumanthShastry  I'm drawing a LineString, and i want to be able to move only the vertices. not adding new ones.

Comment: Currently that functionality does not exist in Openlayers. You have to write that custom code by implementing `ol.interaction.Pointer` interaction.

Comment: I imagined that it was something not implemented yet. Can you give me some more tips?

Comment: I wonder if you override the custom styling and set the minor vertices to use a null style if that will be enough?

Answer (score 1):

**OpenLayers v5.3.0** now features such functionality:

Just pass `insertVertexCondition: ol.events.condition.never` (or whatever condition you'd like) as option to the modify interaction.

**Full example:**

```
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selection,
    insertVertexCondition: ol.events.condition.never
});
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved us ton of time!